# How to send message in discord channel by it's api

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to send a message in my channel. As I have read, I need to pass the message as the content parameter in the post request. Here is the short python code for that

```
import requests

URL = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/super/secret

r = requests.get(URL,data={"content":"123"},headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})

print(r.text)
```

But it gives me a response:

```
<a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: you have used get

Comment: Changed it to post. Now it shows - {"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}

Comment: how do u send messages without logining in?

Answer (score 0):

Discord in their docs [HERE](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference) says:

> Some API and Gateway versions are now non-functioning, and are labeled
>   as discontinued in the table below for posterity. Trying to use these
>   versions will fail and return 400 Bad Request.